# Перебор всевозможных заничений (вариаций) массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия, перебор, ссылка

Дан массив:
`$result_values = array([1,2,3],["A","B","C"],["dog","cat"]);`
Нужно перебрать его следующим образом а именно:

```
1
1-A
1-B
1-C
1-dog
1-cat
1-A-dog
1-A-cat
1-B-dog
1-B-cat
1-C-dog
1-C-cat
```

точно также для следующих элементов в каждом массиве.
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте к каждому массиву пустой элемент (или специальное значение)

Найдите **декартово произведение** массивов (cartesian product).

В каждом промежуточном результате игнорируйте пустые элементы.